# RPC specification

Tags: rpc

Where can I find details about tezos RPC specifications? For example, what are the parameters needed for `originate` to create new smart contract?

I want to write a custom node so I'll need this information to process incoming RPC requests.

Answer (score 3):

In the online documentation!

- http://doc.tzalpha.net/api/openapi.html
- http://doc.tzalpha.net/shell/rpc.html#rpcs-full-description
- http://doc.tzalpha.net/010/rpc.html#rpcs-full-description

Comment: You can use the domain "tezos.gitlab.io" instead of "doc.tzalpha.net".

Comment: And there is a permalink for the currently-active protocol: http://doc.tzalpha.net/active/rpc.html#rpcs-full-description

Answer (score 1):

[OpenAPI Specification](https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/openapi.html)

[Current protocol RPCs Full description](https://tezos.gitlab.io/active/rpc.html#rpcs-full-description)